# Angular7 - Get Response from the API Call

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to Angular 7 and trying to learn how Http Client works. The APi call from the Angular application is made but I get the response like below

[image]

My service.ts is like below

```
export class ReportingFilterService {
 shipmentByProjectResult: any[];

  constructor(service: DataService) {
  }
  getShipmentByPrj(): ShipmentByProject[] {
    return this.shipmentByProjectResult;
   }
 }
```

where ShipmentByProject is a model class

```
export class ShipmentByProject {
Id: string;
project_number: string;
related_project_number: string;
Reporting_Project: string;  
customer_shipto_name: string;
sales_order_TJL_ship_date: Date |string|null;
deliverydate: Date |string|null;
delivery_mode : string;
customer_purchase_order: string;
total_qty: number|null;
}
```

And the component

```
export class ReportingFilterComponent implements OnInit {
  ShipmentList: ShipmentByProject[];
  entityUrl = 'ShipmentDetail/GetByReportingProject?repPrj=000634';

  constructor(service: DataService) {
   service.get<ShipmentByProject[]>(this.entityUrl).subscribe(x => 
  {this.ShipmentList = x });
   }
 ngOnInit() {  }}
```

I am just calling the response in the html like `Reporting filter works!
{{ShipmentList}}`. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is appreciated s I am learning and new to Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your data is in array format so you should loop through your data like this

```
  <li *ngFor="let shipment of ShipmentList">
      {{ shipment.customer_shipto_name }}
  </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data variable 'ShipmentList' is initialised as an array. So you should iterate the array for getting each shipping data as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let shipment of ShipmentList">{{shipment.objectName}} //objectName can be Id,customer_purchase_order etc
</div>
```